# Excel: Select unique text value from column A and get corresponding value in column B

Tags: excel

[image: I need to calculate the third column]

The first 2 columns repeat data in my data export dump tab. I need to get the number of positions for a unique job reference. How can I create the third column?

Comment: I suspect that your question is being down voted because you haven't explained anything. Your title suggest that you could use something like a **VLOOKUP** or **INDEX+MATCH** but your `To This` does not correspond to your title. Can you explain how you get to `To This` from.. well from your `Job Number`

Comment: You should be able to modify @QHarr's query to get your expected column

Comment: Yes thanks...When i uploaded it, all the data was on one line so I've screen dumped it. Yes I should be able to work it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C2 put the following and drag down for as many rows as required

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)>1,"",B2)
```

[image: Data]

Comment: How did you do that so fast? I thought my copy paste from excel didn't work so have done a screen dump...The job reference is the EF/1014 column and the number is a separate column

Comment: Perfect...Thanks so much!